# Wordpress Plugin Youtube API player display

Tags: wordpress, youtube-api

guys.. Can you help me debug my first time wordpress plugin. It's almost 2 weeks I'm working with this and I'm stuck on showing a preview or front-end display..

It's a youtube search api then the result will automatically lists as playlist. I have grab some codes and customized it. but I can't seem to show the player..

here is my core plugin code: http://pastebin.com/hE62zYvm

or you can try to install. I can already fetch data from user.. the only problem I think is for the player to display my search results

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/65217109/youtube_content.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube player offers what sounds like the same functionality out of the box. See http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/new-player-options-for-lists-of-videos.html for more details.

If you specify `listType=search` and `list=YOUR_SEARCH_TERM` as player parameters then you'll get a playlist player that will contain videos matching `YOUR_SEARCH_TERM`.

I'm not sure if that's the exact UX that you're after, but it sounds a lot simpler to implement.